# How to write a tool which executes tests on c, cpp programs in windows?

Tags: testing, cmd

I would like to write a tool in windows which compiles a c/cpp program on windows and executes series of tests on them?

It is like [Spoj.pl](http://www.spoj.pl/) actually.. I wrote a similar thing in linux using `fork()`. But i could not in windows. Can anyone tell where should i start ?

Comment: Are you compiling some high-level language to C (so C is the *object* language of your compiler) or do you want to code yet another *C* compiler (so *C* is the source language of your compiler)?

Comment: No. I would like to implement an onlineJudge like http://spoj.pl which takes C source code and compiles and executes the sourcecode against a set of test cases and produces the result.

Comment: Are you aware of the security issues, if you put that online on a web server?

Comment: What might be the security issues? Can you explain ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows has it's own functions to create new processes but maybe you don't want to go that way. Instead, find out how to run your C compiler from the command line and then use a scripting language like [Python](http://www.python.org/) or [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) to run it and the tests.

The advantage of using a scripting language is that they have powerful tools to create processes and talk to them; plus Python comes with batteries included so it's very simple using it to create nice reports of the test results.